# Pandas create new column with all the entries from another column corresponding to a unique value

Tags: python, pandas

I am sorry if the question is not clear enough. Say I have this dataframe:

```
timestamp source dest size

1          a      b     5
1          c      d     6
2          c      e     7
2          d      a     8
```

From this dataframe I want something like this:

```
timestamp      link        size
 1             a b c d     5 6
 2             c e d a     7 8
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `groupby` method of pandas dataframe.
Make sure that you `size` column contains strings.

```
df['link'] = df['source'] + ' ' + df['dest']
df = df.drop(['source', 'dest'], axis = 1)
newDf = df.groupby('timestamp').agg(lambda col: ' '.join(col))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pivot with a couple added steps since you want to pivot on two columns independently of each other.

```
u = df.melt('timestamp')
m = u['variable'].isin(['source', 'dest'])

u.loc[m, 'variable'] = 'link'

u.pivot_table(
  'value', 'timestamp', 'variable', aggfunc=list)
```

```
variable           link    size
timestamp
1          [a, c, b, d]  [5, 6]
2          [c, d, e, a]  [7, 8]
```

---

An alternative using `rename` first

```
d = dict(source='link', dest='link')

df.rename(columns=d).melt('timestamp').pivot_table(
  'value', 'timestamp', 'variable', aggfunc=list)
```

```
variable           link    size
timestamp
1          [a, c, b, d]  [5, 6]
2          [c, d, e, a]  [7, 8]
```

Comment: It gives [a,c,b,d]  but I really need [a,b,c,d], it is hard to get that?